# IIS 6 WWW in subdomain doesn't redirect

Tags: subdomain

In IIS, I have a subdomain: sub.mydomain.com

BUT, if someone incorrectly types it as: www.sub.mydomain.com  it doesn't work.

How do I resolve this issue?

Thanks!

Comment: Belongs on http://serverfault.com

Comment: Sorry. I posted this there. I didn't know about serverfault.

Answer (score 2):

With IIS6 you cannot create wildcard subdomains, you will have to use DNS (or ISAPI rewrite) to handle *.sub.mydomain.com.

For more information on wildcard subdomains and windows you can actually use ServerFault ;-). See this post here: [Wildcard DNS and subdomains](https://serverfault.com/questions/12124/wildcard-dns-and-subdomains)

For more information on ISAPI rewrite you can use the following page: [Creating Dynamic Subdomains in IIS using ISAPI_Rewrite](http://www.seoconsultants.com/windows/isapi/subdomains/)